# Facebook graph api page feed images

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

I am able to fetch my page feeds by graph api. But the only problem is the pictures
The feeds contain more than 1 pictures however the graph api only return 1 picture for me. How can I fetch all the pictures for the feeds?

thanks
ps.
i fetch the feeds by this api:
https://graph.facebook.com/[page_id]/feed?access_token=[access_token]

Answer (score 12):

Finally I get all the photos of a post by this graph api:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/#{fb_post_id}?fields=attachments&access_token=#{access_token}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:
`{PAGE-ID}/feed?fields=attachments{url,subattachments}`

Comment: It's working for api 2.8. I am using `{PAGE_ID}/posts?fields=attachments`

Answer (score -1):

You need to get attachments by doing this

https://graph.facebook.com/v.2.2/[page_id]/posts?attachments&access_token=[AppID]|[AppSecret]

All the images is in the attachments